# Android Async Task progress on background

Tags: android, asynchronous, background, task

I have an "Create Ad" activity and async tasks for creating in my app. It's working but waiting with a progress dialog and this is boring sometimes because there is a file upload method it may take a while. I want to when user clicked the "Create" button; activity dont destroy, just hide then Async tasks work on behind and progress.

Is there any special keyword for when clicked create button and work on background and hide the creating activity?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How about using a `service` ?

Comment: Can you explain service, a little? Service like what, im using async tasks for it now.

Comment: this is a nice place to start : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will examine it.

Comment: Beyond causing the user to wait, doing network IO in an activity rather than a service is discouraged for reasons discussed here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273753/android-asynctask-memory-leaks)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so you mean using service is better then async tasks?

Comment: Yes and no. ASync tasks have their uses. For example, sorting a large array list before populating a view. But for background tasks like uploading and downloading data then services are preferred.

Comment: This is what i needed. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use Async Task for operations less than 10 seconds because it works on main thread. If your operation is more than this, you should use intent service. It works on background thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was important for me. I didnt now this trick. I have one more little question is service using less memory and network then async task?

Comment: @FurkanAlnıak I don't know what's your mean about less network. Look at : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService

Comment: Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use service for this .[here is the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will examine it.